# Spinner gif/message on new tab

Tags: javascript

I have a button when clicked opens up a new tab and runs a complex sql query for about a minute. During this time the newtab is a blank screen. I would like to put a message on the screen that the request is processing and something is happening. This is mainly so users know it is not just a blank screen, but there actually is something happening behind the scenes so please wait. Is this possible with javascript to perform an action before the tab is loaded?

Comment: jquery `.hide()`, maybe?

Comment: Post the code that causes the SQL query to fire.  Is it a jquery ajax request?  Is this strictly javascript, or is there some other serverside framework triggering the query, like Asp.NET MVC

Comment: The button calls the action window.open command. The url I send inside of the window.open has the params for sql